# Concatenation between URL::action() and Javascript int variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, concatenation

I need to do an AJAX request in laravel, and the url is a concatenation between tne URL::Action method and an Javascript integer variable.

The javascript function in the view is

```
function detailMaintenanceVehicle(vehicleId,placa){

    var url = "{{ URL::action('DetailMaintenanceController@getDetailMaintenance',["+vehicleId+"]) }}";

    console.log(vehicleId); // This prints integer variables 1,2,3..
    console.log(url); // This prints a string http://localhost/.../detailMaintenance/+vehicleId+

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });

}
```

The concatenation uses the variable name, it must use the value.

// Gives  : http://localhost/.../detailMaintenance/+vehicleId+

// I need : http://localhost/.../detailMaintenance/3     (for example)

Please help me. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try as:

```
var url = "{{ URL::action('DetailMaintenanceController@getDetailMaintenance', ['vehicleId' => 'vehicleId']) }}";

url.replace("vehicleId", vehicleId);
```

Comment: It worked and in just one line     var url = ("{{...}}").replace(..);

Answer (score 3):

You should never generate JS with PHP. Create hidden input with data, for example:

```
{!! Form::hidden('url, action('DetailMaintenanceController@getDetailMaintenance)) !!}
```

If your action requires ID, just write partial URL manually.

And then get it in JS:

```
var url = $( "[name='url']" ) + vehicleId;
```

Comment: Yes you are right, in this case was more appropiate to my case pseudocode's answer . Same thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You must create a route for this method controller just like:
    Route::any('ajaxRequest/{vehicleId}',"DetailMaintenanceController@getDetailMaintenance");

then after you need to change in your javascript as below:

```
function detailMaintenanceVehicle(vehicleId,placa){

var url = "{{ URL::to('ajaxRequest/') }}"+vehicleId; //YOUR CHANGES HERE...

console.log(vehicleId); // This prints integer variables 1,2,3..
console.log(url); // This prints a string http://localhost/.../detailMaintenance/+vehicleId+

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: to'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Yest, I used it and it worked, but now I need to do it using URL::action . Same Thanks!